# Why is jQuery Mobile select boxes locking the options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I created two select boxes, one dependent on the other, to select an "user" you need to select an "area", so all "users" that has that "area" will be available when such "area" is selected. It works perfectly when not using jQuery Mobile, but when I put the links and test it, it locks the options. Why is it doing that?

Any help will be profusely appreciated!

**UPDATE:** The weird thing is that it's actually getting the value of the options AKA it's selecting! but it's not "refreshing" the select
 tag with the selected option's text. Try `$('#user').val();` on the console when the select is blank.

To see the error, select `Test` on the first select box,
and then try to select `user` on the second select box.

**Try it here**: http://liveweave.com/1hOGCg

**or**

**My code (try removing the jQuery Mobile links to see it working)**:

```js
localStorage.setItem('dad', '[[1,"asdasd"],[2,"Test"]]');
localStorage.setItem('son', '[[1,1,"Test"],[10,1,"User213"],[2,1,"Test2"],[3,1,"Test3"],[4,1,"Test4"],[5,1,"Test5"],[6,1,"Testtesttest6"],[7,1,"Test7"],[8,1,"Test8"],[9,2,"User"]]');
var dadArray = (localStorage.getItem('dad') !== null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dad')) : '';
var sonArray = (localStorage.getItem('son') !== null) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('son')) : '';
var tempArray = '';

if (localStorage.getItem('dad') === null && localStorage.getItem('son') === null) {
  getData();
}

function getDad(dad, id) {
  var size = dad.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    $(id).append('<option value="' + dad[i][0] + '">' + dad[i][1] + '</option>');
  }
}

function getSon(son, id, dad) {
  var size = son.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (dad == son[i][1]) {
      $(id).append('<option class="area' + son[i][1] + '" value="' + son[i][0] + '">' + son[i][2] + '</option>');
    }
  }
}

$('#areas').change(function() {
  $('#user').empty();
  getSon(sonArray, '#user', $(this).val());
});

$(function() {
  getDad(dadArray, '#areas');
  $('#areas').change();
});

//If localStorage has been erased
/*
function getData(){
tempArray = $.ajax({
url: 'http://sistema.agrosys.com.br/webpro/webadm/wcgsynua',
async: false
});
tempArray = tempArray.responseText;
splitArray(tempArray,dadArray,sonArray);
}

function splitArray(array,dad, son){
var isItDad = true;
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
var bit = array.substring(i, i+1);
if(bit == 's'){
if(array.substring(i, i+4) == 'son='){
isItDad = false; 
}
}
if(isItDad === true){
dad += bit;
}else{
son += bit;
}
}
dadArray = dad;
sonArray = son;
dadArray = dadArray.replace('dad=', '');
sonArray = sonArray.replace('son=', '');
dadArray = dadArray.replace(',[]', '');
sonArray = sonArray.replace(',[]', '');
dadArray = JSON.parse(dadArray);
sonArray = JSON.parse(sonArray);
}
*/
//If localStorage has been erased
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>iterateSelectBox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="areas">
  </select>
  <select id="user">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying a select you need to tell jQM to refresh the widget:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh

Just add

```
$(id).selectmenu( "refresh", true );
```

at the end of getDad() and getSon()

```
function getDad(dad, id) {
  var size = dad.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    $(id).append('<option value="' + dad[i][0] + '">' + dad[i][1] + '</option>');
  }
  $(id).selectmenu( "refresh", true );
}

function getSon(son, id, dad) {
  var size = son.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (dad == son[i][1]) {
      $(id).append('<option class="area' + son[i][1] + '" value="' + son[i][0] + '">' + son[i][2] + '</option>');
    }
  }
  $(id).selectmenu( "refresh", true );
}
```

Comment: So I was right on my update then, it's just needed to be refreshed. Thank you so much helping me with a straight-to-the-point answer +1

Comment: Wait a minute, how will I use JqueryUI and jQuery Mobile together in order to use `$(id).selectmenu( "refresh", true );`?

Comment: @Calne, using jQueryUI and jQuery Mobile together can be a little tricky. Do you really need both?

Comment: I'm getting `selectmenu is not a function` when using jQuery Mobile only, why am I getting it?

Comment: @Calne, here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/f06vLtox/2/  In you posted markup you are adding jQuery twice: jquery-2.1.4.min.js and jquery-latest.min.js. Remove the latest.min. Also put your selectes in a jQM page (div with data-role="page") and put you script within a jQM pagecreate event.

Comment: Oh that's true, holy sh*t I'm a F'ing dumbass, I'm so sorry for that, thank you so much for paying attention and helping me